# Arduino nano select port option is blurred | Driver issue

Tags: arduino-nano

I have just bought arduino nano board. when i connect the board via usb, system detects the new device but i am not able to select port in arduino ide for writing any code on board. I checked my device manager it says

> The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)
>
> There are no compatible drivers for this device.

I have also updated my board and library list in arduino ide.

please help me out?

Comment: What USB<->uart chip is on the board? Usually on the back (often FTDI, CH340G or CPxxxx).

Comment: CH340 is on board

Comment: My PCs and Raspberry Pis that I use to program Arduinos all have already had the CH340 driver installed.  Vista, Win7, Win8.1, Rpi3B with Raspbian - all worked fine.  But it is possible you need to install a driver.  I see your answer describes how to do so.  Kudos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on my nano board CH340G USB<-->uart chip was present, so i installed driver for that chip and everything works fine now. :P

link for the driver (windows 8,10): http://www.arduined.eu/ch340-windows-8-driver-download/

Comment: Good, looks like you managed to fix the issue yourself!

Comment: This is good information to have in the stackexchange database.  Thank you for posting the link.